# !! (not not) vs Boolean() performance

Tags: javascript

I came across the !! (not not) operator in javascript as a way of converting a falsy/truthy value to inverted true/valse and then invert it to get the corresponding true/false. So apparently

```
!!("something")
```

and

```
Boolean("something")
```

are the same. Are there any differences between them? Which one is the preferred one?

I found some related questions ( [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)) but they don't seem to address performance. I hope this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Is your application really so strained on performance that this matters?

Comment: Not an answer to your question: do you have any real world situation where you may even care of any (even measurable) performance gain about this?

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a jsPerf benchmark available [here](http://jsperf.com/bang-bang-vs-boolean).

Comment: http://jsperf.com/boolean2

Comment: Not much difference..Check this out: http://jsperf.com/bool-not-not

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes. My curiousness.

Comment: @Entomo good reason! Well I think _code path_ for such things is pretty variable and you'll get completely different results on, for example, Chrome and IE. Not so reliable tests...

Comment: OK. the links provided are interesting so I will have a look. Thanks

Comment: @blunderboy the test was wrong, as the `||` meant it only did the first conversion and skipped the rest. I've fixed it now.

Comment: `!!x` and `new Boolean(x)` are not the same: if you compare those two expressions, they will fail a strict equality check (`===`) and they give different results for `typeof` (which is why they fail the strict equality). `new Boolean` creates an object, while `!!` returns a primitive.

Comment: !!x and Boolean(x) pass the equality check. new Boolean(x) is false indeed.

Comment: @Quentin, I don't see this answered in the duplicated post in any way. Not at the first peek at least and I don't want to spend my morning digesting that other huge one. Please, revert the duplicated post. I already know how to fish but in this case I want a steamy delicious baked fish instead of a fishing cane, if you know what I mean.

Comment: #ANSWER: They're pretty close as far as performance goes. I ran the tests and some times they came out one faster than the other, but sometimes it went the other way. **It's a toss up**. The bigger question is **readability**. Boolean is definitely more explicit and easy for anyone to understand. !! has a much smaller footprint. *It's up to your team which to use.*